# Open Source Clearcase Alternatives

Tags: windows, svn, workflow, clearcase, dvcs

I'm helping get the SCM set up for a new program, and we're currently in the process of deciding on a VCS.

The main contenders at this point are SVN, ClearCase, SVN+DVCS, and just a DVCS.

At the moment, the team is leaning towards either SVN or SVN+DVCS.  We want to avoid the expense and administration costs of ClearCase, but want the workflow and versioning options it offers.  I brought forward the option of using a DVCS as well, and the idea is being considered.

For the DVCS, we're considering Mercurial, Bazaar, and Git.  The team feels comfortable with SVN, but don't think it'll offer the versatility needed, which is why we're looking at the DVCS on top of SVN option.

Does anyone have any advice (e.g. existing tools, processes) for getting such a setup going?

Concerns include:

- Ease of setup
- Setting up workflows (developing <-> code reviews -> test -> trunk, then trunk -> integration test branch -> release with bug fixes put into the release branches), auditing (found a bug, when was it introduced)
- Generating metrics
- Reasonable learning curve for developers used to ClearCase.
- Windows development
- Issue tracker integration (probably going to be Redmine, though it isn't set in stone)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an administrator of ClearCase, I would rule out that tool unless you have a complex merge workflow.

The **[workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216212#216228)** you mention involves being able to branch, fix and then merge back easily, which should not be in favor of SVN.

The biggest trap when you are used to ClearCase (espacially non-UCM ClearCase) is the "composition" of a config spec.
If you choose a DVCS (Mercurial, Bazaar -- or Git since it [works really well on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783906/git-under-windows-msys-or-cygwin)), you would [*not* be able to get the same "inheritance effect" -- (when you are selecting different versions with different successive select rules --](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763099/flexible-vs-static-branching-git-vs-clearcase-accurev): as said in that answer:

> In a purely central VCS, you can define your workspace (in ClearCase, your "view" either snapshot or dynamic) with whatever rules you want.
>   That would not be practical in a DVCS (as in "Distributed"): when you are making a branch with it, you need to do so with a starting point and a content clearly defined and easily replicated to other repositories.

If you are using ClearCase UCM, that means identifying coherent sets of files, which can only be achieved through - for instance - [Git submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932586/middle-ground-between-submodules-and-branches).
The complexity is higher with those DVCS, since they do not record the dependencies between modules (or "set of files") the way ClearCase UCM does.

So, to recap:

- Ease of setup: all the mentioned DVCS are easy to setup. What must be taken into account is the administration in terms of user access.
- Setting up workflows: a DVCS supports any kind of workflow, even a centralized one, or a public-private one, or.... Regarding finding a bug, they all support some kind of [bisect process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959324/finding-bugs-by-bisecting-searching-revision-history-and-untestable-commits-r).
- Generating metrics: if by that you mean "metrics about the code managed", they all support some complete log system able to display a lot of information about what has changed.
  But in term of "metrics about the tool" (speed of a process or space taken by data), the DVCS tools mentioned are considered much faster than SVN (see [here as an example](http://cafenate.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/more-subversion-vs-mercurial-metrics/)).
- Reasonable learning curve for developers used to ClearCase: the GUI can be a factor to alleviate the learning curve, but a DVCS is very different from ClearCase, as this "[core concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008#645771)" answer illustrates.
- Windows development: they all work well on the Windows platform, with maybe a slight advantage (better integration) to Mercurial or Bazaar.
- Issue tracker integration (probably going to be Redmine, though it isn't set in stone): Redmine supports now most of them (and not just SVN as it did at the beginning)

Answer (score 3):

What's the problem with Git? I'm using Git on Windows right now. It works just fine.
[Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) is very useful if you'd like some explorer integration, if that is your issue.

Comment: Git is slow on windows compared to Linux. And TortoiseGit is not really usable right now. That is the problem.

Comment: If you are a Windows user, why do you really give a shit how fast it is on Linux? The important thing is how it compares to your Windows alternatives (its faster). Tortoise is totally unimportant. Gitgui works just fine, and it is designed around the capabilities of Git.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with clearcase but hopefully the following will help some. Your question leaves out several pieces of information that I would take into account before deciding. First how much source code will you have? While SVN is good on medium to large projects for truly huge ones like the Linux kernel Git will provide much better performance. Second what IDE are you using? While Mercurial, Git, and SVN all have visual studio and eclipse plugins there quality very. According to the Wikipedia article on Redmine any of the SCM systems you are looking at will integrate. The following blog may be helpful for you since its written buy a guy who writes a SCM system for a living.
http://www.ericsink.com/

Comment: There was a SO question on Git/VS integration. I can't seem to find it, but my comment (which still stands) is that with an edit/merge system like Git you don't really *need* VS integration. You pull everything down, *then* do your VS stuff (code, debug, etc), *then* merge. There's no need to constantly go back to the revision control system while you are developing, like there is when you need to manage locks all the time.

Comment: While that is true it's often habit for developers to use the IDE instead of a commandline version control, so if you can have basic integration to pull and merge all else being equal you probably want the one with pull and merge support in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you could drop the requirement that it needs to run on Windows then I would recommend looking at  [Aegis](http://aegis.sourceforge.net).

Comment: After looking in more detail, Aegis is not a version control system.  It's designed to wrap around a version control system (and other tools) to provide additional capabilities such as automated testing, shared object libraries, and code review.  I can still see it being useful in other contexts, so thanks for sharing it.